# Fill (The first indian physician graduated in 1886 . About 125 years later,Indian women had started to outnumber men in admissions__medical colleges.)

Tags: grammar

Fill in the blank.

`The first indian physician graduated in 1886 . About 125 years later,Indian women had started to outnumber men in admissions__medical colleges.`

This question came  in my english exam . I filled in  `to`.
However  `in` makes perfect sense
to me as well.
Which one is the correct answer ?
If none of them are correct then what is the correct answer?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to say "to" and wrong to say "in".

The answer should be "admissions to/into medical college", and not "admissions in medical college". You can "admit into college", and you can get an "admission into college", but there is no example/case where you can "admit **in** college".